# Изображения внутри <pattern> не отображаются в старых версиях браузера Mozilla

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg, firefox, pathpattern

На старых версиях mozilla изображения внутри тега pattern не отображаются. Как заставить браузер это делать? Имеется примерно такой html на странице:

```css
svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.example {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #000;
}

.example a {
  transition: all 0s linear;
}

.barbara {
  fill: url(#barbara);
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <svg version="1.1" 
       width="1425" 
       height="1267" 
       viewBox="0 0 1425 1267" 
       baseProfile="full" 
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
       xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
    <g class="barbara">
      <a xlink:href="example.com">
        <path d="M2652,2652H0V0H2652Z"/>
      </a>
    </g>
    <pattern id="barbara" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="1425" height="1267" viewbox="0 0 1425 1267">
      <image xlink:href="barbara.png" width="1425" height="1267" />
    </pattern>
  </svg>
</div>
```

В опере и хромиумах все отображается корректно, внутри path отображаются png-изображения, а mozilla (и я подозреваю, что safari тоже) не может их обработать. Я понимаю, что надо помочь браузеру понять, что там есть изображения и их надо обработать, но не знаю как, и гугление не помогает. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Я понимаю, что mozilla обновляется автоматически, но есть множество людей, которые используют старые версии по той или иной причине. Хотелось бы чтобы для них все выглядело так же.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте добавить единицы измерения, например `px` в размеры изображения

`<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHYc7.jpg"  width="1425px" height="1267px" />`

*Для изображений*, многие старые версии браузеров не понимают в чем указаны размеры: в процентах, относительных или абсолютных единицах измерения, если указаны только цифры и поэтому не рендерят изображение.

```css
svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.example {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #000;
}

.example a {
  transition: all 0s linear;
}

.barbara {
  fill: url(#barbara);
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <svg version="1.1" 
       width="1425" 
       height="1267" 
       viewBox="0 0 1425 1267" 
       baseProfile="full" 
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
       xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
    <g class="barbara">
      <a xlink:href="example.com">
        <path d="M2652,2652H0V0H2652Z"/>
      </a>
    </g>
    <pattern id="barbara" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="1425" height="1267" viewbox="0 0 1425 1267">
      <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHYc7.jpg"  width="1425px" height="1267px" />
    </pattern>
  </svg>
</div>
```

2. Ещё один нюанс, но это уже касается ссылок
   (Это дополнительная информация)

Готовится к выходу версия **SVG2**, где `xlink:href` объявлено depricate (устаревшим, нежелательным) и предлагается заменить ссылки, как в HTML на обычные ссылки `href`
Но safari не понимает такой формы записи, так как новый стандарт ещё не внедрён.
Но новые версии `Chrome` и  `Firefox` уже внедрили `href`

Что же нужно сделать, чтобы приложение было кроссбраузерным?
В литературе и на практике предлагается указывать одновременно обе записи,  для одних браузеров сработает новая  запись `href` для других старая запись `xlink :href`

```
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHYc7.jpg" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHYc7.jpg" 
 width="1425px" height="1267px" />
```

```css
svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.example {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #000;
}

.example a {
  transition: all 0s linear;
}

.barbara {
  fill: url(#barbara);
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <svg version="1.1" 
       width="1425" 
       height="1267" 
       viewBox="0 0 1425 1267" 
       baseProfile="full" 
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
       xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
    <g class="barbara">
      <a xlink:href="example.com">
        <path d="M2652,2652H0V0H2652Z"/>
      </a>
    </g>
    <pattern id="barbara" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="1425" height="1267" viewbox="0 0 1425 1267">
      <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHYc7.jpg" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHYc7.jpg" width="1425px" height="1267px" />
    </pattern>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Версия Mozilla Firefox 49 - не помогло. На 56 уже отображаются и без плясок. Подозреваю, что эта версия просто не умеет обрабатывать SVG.
А вот за информацию по ссылкам спасибо!

Comment: @Tony  Благодарю. У меня нет старых версий FF Но я очень давно работаю с SVG Наверняка и с этой версией 49 работал уже. У меня сложилось твердое впечатление за эти годы, что FF всегда наиболее правильно работал с SVG/  по сравнению с другими браузерами Значит причина в чём-то другом. Давайте искать дальше её

Comment: Сам то контур и SVG отображаются, и ссылки работают. Все точно так, как должно быть, кроме заливки в виде картинок, содержащихся в <pattern>. Возможно их обработку добавили позже?

Comment: @Tony а вам контур нужен вокруг SVG или большего размера, чем SVG холст Так как path квадрата   имеет размер 2652х2652 а svg 1425х 1267 может в этом причина? Давайте я немного перепишу файл, а вы попробуете

Comment: Нет, нет. Это моя вина и path я взял с потолка для примера, чтобы невставлять 10к-символьный path. В проекте у меня другой. С ним никаких проблем нет. Есть только проблема с заливкой контура картинкой. и только в старой версии FF. Уже в 56 версии, до которой автоматически обновилась 49, все стало отображаться корректно.

Comment: @Tony Обычно заполнение картинкой с помощью pattern используют, когда нужно заполнить круг, треугольник изображением, а у вас просто прямоугольник равный размерам картинки. Попробуйте просто добавить через тег <image> без паттерна или в паттерне убрать лишний viewBox

Comment: У меня в проекте карта региона, разделенная на районы со сложным контуром, которые заливаются гербами этих районов. Я попробовал сделать то, что вы посоветовали и если просто убрать теги pattern - можно все с нуля начинать. Viewbox там не лишние, потому что у меня 25 сложных path внутри одного большого path. А если viewbox убрать то картинка просто пропадает.

Comment: @Tony Хорошо.Уверен, что найдете и устраните причину. Желаю удачи в выполнении проекта

Comment: Спасибо, что попытались помочь!